# Подскажите пример проекта на Symfony4

Tags: php, symfony

После отказа от бандлов каталоги Controller, Entity, Repository and etc находятся в src. Если нужно поделить проект на функционалы, то приходится создавать Controller/*name*, Entity/*name* ... дополнительно отделив сервисы в каталог Services

Подскажите правильный путь или направление

Comment: "Подскажите направление" - куда вы хотите дойти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отказ от бандлов не означает, что нельзя использовать старую структуру. Отказ от бандлов означает, что пропадает функционал, который заставлял ранеее "регистрировать" бандлы в `AppKernel`, "наследовать" бандлы через метод `getParent()`. Но мы всё равно можем разбивать структуру кода на неймспейсы, если нам это удобно.

Например, в коде [Symfony Demo](https://github.com/symfony/demo) мы видим такую структуру:

```
/src
--/Command
--/Controller
--/Entity
----/Post.php
----/User.php
```

Но нам ведь ничего не запрещает (при необходимости) разбить это на:

```
/src
--/User
----/Command
----/Controller
----/Entity
------/User.php
--/Post
----/Command
----/Controller
----/Entity
------/Post.php
```

Однако, стоит отметить, что это будет полезно только в случае больших монолитных приложений, и делать такую структуру на первых этапах разработки бессмысленно. Намного логичнее будет разбить приложение по мере роста (к счастью, современные IDE отлично справляются с автоматизацией таких процессов).

Несколько ссылок с текстом от Fabien Potencier:

- [Symfony 4: Directory Structure](https://medium.com/@fabpot/symfony-4-directory-structure-5b84bd1ce65a)
- [Symfony 4: Monolith vs Micro](http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-monolith-vs-micro.html)

Comment: По сути вы правы, последний вариант как біло раньше, а сейчас поексперементировав понял что контроллеры, формы и шаблоны имеют одну структуру, а сущности они сами по себе. Если контроллеры разбиваются на admin, api и др, то сущьность продукт они и там и там одна. Просто по началу было не привычно.